# Фреймворки для конфигурирования

Tags: java

Какие есть фреймворки для работы с конфигурацией, не считая Apache Commons Configuration?
Есть ли какие-то дополнительные библиотеки к Apache Commons Configuration, для сериализации/десериализации, документирования?

Answer (score 1):

Есть к примеру [Typesafe Config](https://github.com/typesafehub/config).

Не очень понятно, что вы собираетесь сериализовывать и документировть.

Comment: Есть допустим класс MyConfig, с набором полей. Он сериализуется в файл myconfig.xml с помощью JAXB, потом соответственно считывается.
Если бы была пара конфигов небольших, особо вопросов не было бы.  
Хотелось бы: перенести настройки в БД (полностью или частично), сохранить конфиги в виде классов, описать нотациями поля в конфиге (тип, комментарий, допустимые значения и т.п.), на основе аннотаций выполнять проверки при сериализации/десериализации, на основе аннотаций формировать документацию.

Comment: @Rustam не вижу смысла выносить конфиги в сериализуемый Java-код, т.к. это тоже самое, только с дополнительным преобразованием (сериализацией).

Comment: @a_gura если конфигурация у нас в сериализуемом Java-коде, то как минимум получаем следующие плюсы: безопасность типов, например HttpClient getHttpClient(MyHttpConfiguration cfg) - сюда не подсунешь случайно левый конфиг; удобство использования, config.getPort() вместо config.getInteger("MyHttpConfiguration.port"); быстрее отработает чем получение настройки по имени.

Comment: @Russtam Скорость вам не особо важна (если только время старта приложения не является для вас важнейшим KPI). Плюс в типобезопасности парируется минус необходимости компиляции и сериализации.

Comment: @a_gura если в коде настройка часто используется, то скорость важна. Компиляция так вообще не причем, т.к. разницы что "зашито" в коде - класс или имена параметров, особо нет. Загрузка конфигурации происходит редко, поэтому наличие или отсутствие сериализации не важно. Смысла спорить не вижу, т.к. каждый делает как ему удобнее. Меня интересуют существующие библиотеки и фреймворки, чтобы как можно меньше плодить велосипедов.